# Node.js and Redis: problems with GET a key

Tags: node.js, redis

I have surfed through different other questions here in StackOverflow, but I didn't find any solution to my problem. Here it is.

I have developed a service in Node.js, using Redis to write and read keys. Here is the code of my class:

```
import config from 'config'
import {PaginationResult} from '../types/Pagination'
import {createClient} from 'redis'
import {RedisClientType} from '@redis/client/dist/lib/client'

export class RedisManager {
    private _client: RedisClientType

    constructor() {
        this._client = createClient(config.get('redis'))

        this._client.connect()

        this._client
            .on('ready', () => {
                console.info('Redis is ready')
            })
            .on('error', (error: string) => {
                console.error(error)
                console.error(`Redis error, service degraded: ${error}`)
            })
    }

    async save(key: string, value: string, ttl?: number): Promise<any> {
        if (ttl) {
            await this._client.setEx(key, ttl, content)
        } else {
            await this._client.set(key, value)
        }
    }

    async get(key: string): Promise<string | null> {
        return await this._client.get(key)
    }
}
```

Now, I can successfully use the `save` method, like this: `await redis.save('sample_key', 'sample_content')`.

The problem is that I cannot read the content of `sample_key` from Redis, even if `sample_key` exists (I inspect by Redis.app). Here is the code I use to get the information from Redis: `const info = await redisManager.get('sample_key')`. I always obtain `undefined`

Comment: Try validating your key for trailing whitespaces before passing it to the _client.get function

Comment: @FaarizMohammed the key is already trimmed